# Having trouble adding users from a different domain forest to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have two domain forests, lets say DomanA & DomainB. 
Currently, there is NO external trust relationship from DomanA to DomainB.

What i currently have is the opposite: an external outgoing relationship from DomainB to DomainA. So users from DomanA are able to access resources in DomanB but not vice versa.

So, SSRS is setup in DomanB (this is also the domain i'm in) & i'm able to grant permissions to any user in DomanB.

However, when i try to grant permissions to a user in DomanA, i get the following error

> "The user or group name "DomainA\username" is not recognized"

I fired up Fiddler & saw that is not reachable when the error occurs (returns code 404)

https://myurl.abc.de.org/Reports/api/v1.0/ReportServerInfo/Model.SetSystemPolicies

Any ideas on what options i have to overcome this?

Comment: Is this production or just test/dev? If latter, then could you try removing the server from the domain and re-adding it to the domain and see if that helps.

Comment: it is a test environment but a direct replica of production.

Comment: So did you try what I recommended above?